# textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable returns different value 0 and -2

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have code to check isLanguageAvailable from TextToSpeech.

```
textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
```

The problem is the above line executed 2 times within 1 seconds. It returns 0 for the first time and -2 for the second time. Both the times textToSpeech, locale object is same.

Any idea on what circumstances it will behave like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some more code? And elaborate at what time this piece of code is executed?

Answer (score 0):

TextToSpeech engine got disconnected in the middle. Thats the reason for above mentioned scenario.